# Preventing repetition of SQL, Mysqli_Query, Mysqli_Fetch_Array, Prepared Statements

Tags: php

So I noticed one thing, and something that hardly pops up when someone like me who is relatively new to PHP tries his best to create clean and reusable OOP code. As many newbies there is also a pitfall into trying to create "intelligent" code. Therefore I thought I would ask if my thoughts about creating functions for those common tasks are trivial or efficient.

Imagine all those beeing inside a base class:

**Some basic idea**:

```
function sel($rows, $table, $compA, $logic, $compB) {
    if ($compA && $compB == false) {
       return $sql = SELECT $rows FROM $table;
    }
    else {
       return $sql = SELECT $rows FROM $table WHERE $compA $logic $compB;
    }
}

function query($sql) {
    return $result = mysqli_query(this->connection, $sql)
}

function fetch($result) {
    return mysqli_fetch_array($result)
}

function prepared(types, $data) {
    $stmt->bind_param($types, $username);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

As you can see I am not sure if this is a dumb move in trying to be smart, especially when it comes to creating a function for SQL commands or if this is the right path. Especially SQL selects, updates, inserts etc are never really the same. The first might as well be a useless idea.

I would appreciate some feedback. Do these functions or at least the basic idea behind it make sense to you or shouldnt I worry about a little bit of repetition?

Comment: Is replacing one line by another (that might cause problems) really useful?

Comment: @FirstOne not really. I just feel that there is a lot of repetition going on

Comment: This is an approach thousands of people tried, especially people not yet that experienced in coding, php coding in particular. It works, but is questionable, since it does not really lead anywhere. In short: you are trying to abstract the abstraction. _What for?_

Comment: @arkascha you are right. Thinking about it, it is really like driving a car on top of a car

Comment: @RyanVincent although arkascha is right, im trying to abstract the abstraction